# Where are the community guidelines in dealing with plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, support

Plagiarism online is something of [a plague](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/06/28/technology/lessons-in-internet-plagiarism.html).

What guidelines does this site set itself in detecting and dealing with such cases?

Are there any?

And if so, can someone point me towards it?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/334566

Comment: Plagiarism online is indeed a plague, but perhaps use a newer source (not nearly 19 years old - [Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog) [time](https://www.modernservantleader.com/technology/internet-time-think-in-dog-years/) and all)?